# How to insert a symbol in every object in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of time that looks like this:

```
["0531","0950", "1232", "2241" ..."]
```

I need to insert a ":" inside every object in the list, in such a way I have:

```
["05:31", "09:50", ...]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `print([i[:2] + ':' + i[-2:] for i in ["0531","0950", "1232", "2241"]])`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: `[datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(t, '%H%M'), '%H:%M') for t in the_list]`

Answer (score 2):

```py
old_list = ["0531", "0950", "1232", "2241"]
new_list = [a[0:2] + ":" + a[2:4] for a in old_list]
```

Then `print(new_list)` will print out `['05:31', '09:50', '12:32', '22:41']`.

**How does it work?**

It creates a list, where each element is the first two characters of each element in the original list `a[0:2]` concatenated with a `:` concatenated with the next two `a[2:4]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a comprehension:

```
>>> l = ["0531","0950", "1232", "2241"]
>>> [f"{s[:2]}:{s[2:]}" for s in l]
['05:31', '09:50', '12:32', '22:41']
```